# Reachability service malfunctioning in Xcode run

Tags: iphone, xcode, reachability

I am developing an iPhone application that needs an internet connection, so I used Reachability class files provided by Apple sample code into my project. 
I imported "Reachability.m" in my view controller and used the following code to check internet connection

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

To check for connection,

```
    if (internetStatus != NotReachable)
{
     My code to run.
}
```

Well, this was working fine until last night. But now internet status does not detect No internet connection. My Wifi is turned off and I checked to see the status using these if statements

```
if(internetStatus==ReachableViaWiFi){
    NSLog(@"Reachable VIA WIFI");
}
if(internetStatus==ReachableViaWWAN) {
    NSLog(@"Reachable VIA WLAN");
}
if(internetStatus==NotReachable){
    NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
}
```

But it displays Reachable Via WIFI. My wifi is turned off, I cannot find what the problem is. I have not even changed a single line of code from the last time it worked, the other night.

I am testing it on Xcode simulator.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-a-connection-on-ios/8812506#8812506

Comment: I didnot find the answer in that link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812074/app-crashing-when-using-reachability-classes-to-check-for-internet-connection

Comment: "Turn Airport off" and test it :)

Comment: My Airport is Off, but I found out I had hardware problems no code when I checked System preferences. :D Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you disable WiFi, your device try to access internet from your carrier. This is the reason for status ReachableViaWWAN. When you disable your 3G from device setting then only your device will show you that you are not connected and then -

```
 if(internetStatus==NotReachable)
 {
       NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
 }
```

this condition will be true.

Comment: My bad, I edited in my question, the output was Reachable via WIFI not WLAN..  still my Wifi connects to internet through either Wifi or Ethernet, while testing my Laptop doesnot have any other means of connecting to internet

Comment: You are not testing on Device?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if([self connected] ) 
  {
    NSLog(@"Internet connected\n");
  } 


- (BOOL)connected 
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];  
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus]; 
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

You can get rechability class [here : Download sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) and add Reachability.h and Reachability.m into your project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my Problem.
There was no problem with Reachability at all, my MAC showed Ethernet Connected even though no connection was made, so it was causing all the problem.
Got next question for Stack overflow considering hardware problems now :P 
Thank you all for trying to help :)